# SQL want to get the unique high price for every date including time

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
 select distinct 
     date, max(high) 
 from 
     `eurusdm1.eurdata112021.forexdata` 
 group by 
     date
```

Output from current query:

```
1    2021-08-06     1.17636
2    2021-08-09     1.17689
3    2021-08-10     1.17428
4    2021-08-11     1.17533
```

I am trying to add a time column to this table that is located in the table, but I am not sure how to accomplish this, so I just want to display the time field named time, along with this query here. This is just for a Euro/U.S. Dollar currency query to get the time that the high price was reached during the day, since the max(high) only happens once per day.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` with `QUALIFY` here:

```sql
SELECT date, time, high
FROM eurusdm1.eurdata112021.forexdata
WHERE TRUE
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY high DESC) = 1;
```

Comment: it gives me an error: QUALIFY clause must be used in conjunction with WHERE or GROUP BY or HAVING clause

Comment: Try putting `QUALIFY` into a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Excellent job sir! Well done! It works great.